# Python Data transformation If df[column] = "A" then df[column] = 1 - (Substitue "A" with 1)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transformation, substitution

I am new to Python and have a large dataset that I'll be building several regression models for.  There are several features that use te values A-Z within the observation.  I want to substitute those A-Z values to 1-26 so that I can include them in the regression model.  I could use getdummies but it will return too many variables.  I'm hoping to transform the variable, or all of them if possible by substituting the "A" with a 1, "B" with a 2 etc.  Most of my searches for if, then statements perform a function as opposed to transforming data.  I've used NP.where to transform binary variables but never anything this large.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: example of your data and the code you have tried?

Comment: Does `df` imply a pandas dataframe?  Add the right tag!

Comment: Post updated as requested

Comment: @R_P_Phillips maybe instead of a photo you could post a code snippet with a Minimum Working Example of what your data looks like, what you already tried and what you want to achieve as an end result? To me it's still unclear what you are asking. Do you want to _substitute_ the letters with the corresponding numbers in the _same column_?

Comment: Use https://repl.it/languages/python3 to create an executable code example that is just complex enough, to cover your problem. Include this code in your question and you will receive help within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you need, I think you should just create a mapping from uppercase letters to alphabet position integers. Then you can map those letters to their respective positions using pandas `map`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 
                        'letter_flag': [np.nan, 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A']})

# Dictionary comprehension to create a mapping from uppercase letters to postions
# i.e. {'A': 1, 'B': 2, ..., 'Z': 26}
letter_mapping = {letter: str(index) for index, letter in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, start=1)}

# Create new column with the mapping
df['mapped_flag'] = df['letter_flag'].map(letter_mapping)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: You could accept and/or upvote the answer if it has been useful to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with.  It works perfectly and can be duplicated by changing the column name.  Thank you.

```
Disq_and_Qual_flag_Mapped = { np.nan : 0, 'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3, 'D' : 4,  'E' : 5, 'F' : 6, 'G' : 7, 'H' : 8, 'I' : 9,
                             'J' : 10, 'K' : 11, 'L' : 12, 'M' : 13, 'N' : 14, 'O' : 15, 'P' : 16, 'Q' : 17, 'R' : 18, 'S' : 19,
                             'T' : 20, 'U' : 21, 'V' : 22, 'W' : 23, 'X' : 24, 'Y' : 25, 'Z' : 26}


df['Disq_and_Qual_flag2'] = df['Disq_and_Qual_flag'].map(Disq_and_Qual_flag_Mapped)

df.head()
```